# Using cereal to send data through a handle

Tags: haskell

Could someone show me an example of using cereal (`Data.Serialize`) to send data through a Handle received from `connectTo` or `accept` in the `Network` package?

Comment: Sounds like a breakfast problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this turns out to be really easy when using a few packages:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary
import Data.Conduit.Cereal
import Data.Serialize

-- where h is a `Handle` to a socket or whatever

-- Write data
a = 123 :: Integer
runResourceT $ sourcePut (put a) $$ sinkHandle h

-- Read data
a <- runResourceT $ sourceHandle h $$ sinkGet get
```

**After some testing it seems i can't send an receive more than once...**